# how to use inherited variable in c++

Tags: c++, inherited

I have a question to inherited variables. Parts of my sourcecode:

```
class Piston{           //abstract class        
   ...                  //virtual functions        
};

class RectangularPiston: public Piston
{
  ...                   //non virtual implementation of the Piston functions
  bool setGridSize(...) //this function doesn't exists in the Piston class
  {
    ...
  }
}

class Transducer{       //abstract class
    ...                 //virtual functions
  protected:
    Piston *m_piston;
};

class RectilinearTransducer: public Transducer
{
    ... //non virtual implementation of the Piston functions
    bool setGridSizeOfPiston(...)
    {
        return m_piston->setGridSize(...);  //doesn't work
    }

}
```

RectilinearTransducer holds a m_piston, which is always a RectlinearPiston!
But m_piston is inherited by the Transducer class and I can't use the setGridSize()-function.

> error message: error C2039: 'setGridSize': Is no element of 'Piston'
>
> The function setGridSize doesn't exists in the Piston class...

How can I solve this Problem?
Should I overwrite the m_piston variable like I can do it with virtual functions? The m_piston variable exists as Piston* m_piston, because I inherited it by the Transducer class.

Thanks for help

Comment: what's the error message? is setGridSize() public ?

Comment: error C2039: 'setGridSize': is no element of 'Piston'

Comment: please update your error message in question

Comment: Is one of the virtual functions in `Piston` `setGridSize(...)`?

Comment: is it possible to overwrite the m_piston variable like I can overwrite virtual functions?

Comment: If `m_piston` is _always_ a `RectlinearPiston` then declare it as one instead of `Piston`

Comment: but <code>m_piston</code> ist a <code>Piston</code> because I inherited it like this by <code>Transducer</code>...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't make `setGridSize` a virtual function in the parent then you might want to add a function that simply casts `m_piston` to `RectangularPiston*` then call this function when your class needs to refer to `m_piston`.

```
RectangularPiston* getRecPiston() {
    return static_cast<RectangularPiston*>(m_piston);
}

bool setGridSizeOfPiston(...) {
        return getRecPiston()->setGridSize(...)        
}
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast` returns NULL if it cannot perform the cast. If you **know** that `m_piston` is **always** a `RectangularPiston` then use `static_cast` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `setGridSize` a virtual function of `Piston` (either pure virtual or otherwise).

e.g

```
class Piston {
  protected: (or public)
     virutal bool setGridSize(..) = 0;
...
```